# Handling multiple parameters in app.param()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, middleware

I’m working on an API in Express.js and trying to implement an `app.param()` function that handles the id parameter in a GET request:

```
app.param('id', (req, res, next, id) => {
    const envelopeIndex = Number(id);
    const envelopeId = envelopes.findIndex(envelope => envelope.id === envelopeIndex);
    if (envelopeId === -1) {
        res.status(400).send("Error: No envelope found with this ID");
    }
    req.id = envelopeId;
    next();
});
```

For another POST request handler that transfers some amount from one envelope to another (through their IDs), I also want to validate two route parameters that are both IDs (/envelopes/:from/:to/).

My questions:

1. Can I refactor the middleware above so that it handles multiple parameters and I don’t have to repeat myself?
2. If so, is there a way I can dynamically assign to the request object the validated ID (e.g. if I am validating ID of 'from', it assigns req.senderId the validated ID, etc.)

I tried:

- Repeating the middleware three times (once per route parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.id = envelopeId;`   Be careful poluting the `req` object with custom fields, it could effect other middlewares, the params are already on the `req` object anyway,  `req.params.id`.

By avoiding the above, it also makes your problem a little easier to handle.

You could just create 2 named params that point to the same function.

eg.

```
const handleId = (req, res, next, id) => {
    const envelopeIndex = Number(id);
    const envelopeId = envelopes.findIndex(envelope => envelope.id === envelopeIndex);
    if (envelopeId === -1) {
        res.status(400).send("Error: No envelope found with this ID");
    }
    next();
}); 

app.param('id', handleId);
app.param('id_to', handleId);
```

Your POST route could then just be ->

```
app.post('/envelopes/:id/:id_to/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  console.log(req.params.id_to);
  res.end('ok');
})
```